# ¿Dónde esta la condición de race que hace que no se ejecuten todos los threads?

Tags: java

Creo una clase derivada de thread (mithread), ejecuto con cada thread una cuenta
de 0 a 10 aleatoria esperando en cada iteración 100ms pero ni mucho menos
la consola saca todas las frases que escribe,como si el thread acabase antes.

```
import java.lang.Thread;

public class mian2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Random ren=new java.util.Random();
        java.util.ArrayList<mithread> threads=new java.util.ArrayList<mithread>();
        for(int i=0;i<24;i++) {
            boolean  b=threads.add(new mithread(ren.nextInt()%10));
            System.out.println(b);

        }   
   for(mithread a : threads) {
       a.start();
   }



 for(mithread c: threads) {
     try {
     c.join();
     }catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());     


     };//catch
 }//for



}//mian 2 main
}//class
class mithread extends Thread{
    protected int num=0;
    public mithread(int num) {
        super();
        this.num=num;

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {
            try {
                sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            };
            System.out.println("thread "+this.getId()+" va por "+i+" numero de "+this.num);
        }

    }
}
```

La ejecución es aleatoria y los resultados varían cada vez pero rara vez ejecuta mas de 7 u 8 threads

Comment: en donde estas esperando que cada thread termine? ;)

Comment: espero que acabe en for(mithread c: threads){ c.join(); }

Comment: ahi no estas esperando, solo los estas recorriendo todos threads hasta que termine de a 1... cual seria tu idea? que ejecuten todos en paralelo? mira la documentacion de [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

Comment: si mi idea es que funcionen en paralelo

Comment: debe existir un mecanismo de coordinacion porque  en windows 8.1 al usar threads la salida me salia mezclada e ilegible al intentar escribir todos a la vez